# How can I delete a record in mysql via ASP.net API and Postman?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, postman, sql-delete

I would like to delete a record in my mysql database. In web api, i wrote something like this:-

```
[Route("~/api/product/wishlist/{user_id}")]
        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int user_id)
        {

            try
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = WebApiConfig.conn();
                MySqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand();
                query.CommandText = "delete from user_wishlist where user_id = @user_id";
                MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
                conn.Open();
                MyReader2 = query.ExecuteReader();


                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data Deleted");
                while (MyReader2.Read())
                {
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Data in database as below:-

[image]

In Postman, i delete in this way but seems like records still exist in my database. Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:-

query.CommandText = "delete from user_wishlist where user_id = @user_id";

WITH

query.CommandText = "delete from user_wishlist where user_id = " + user_id;

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, overlook on that mistake, thanks for alert ! appreciated!